# How to use modalPresentationStyle .fullscreen in React Native navigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am trying to create my first React Native application. I have a login screen from which I want to navigate to a register screen if users want to sign up.

To achieve this, I was thinking of opening a modal above the first screen (login). I created the following:

```
import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native";
import { createStackNavigator } from "@react-navigation/stack";
const Stack = createStackNavigator();

function RegisterScreen({ navigation }) {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <Text style={{ fontSize: 30 }}>Register Screen</Text>
      <Button onPress={() => navigation.goBack()} title="Go back" />
    </View>
  );
}

function MyStack() {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator>
      <Stack.Group>
        <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={LoginScreen} options={{ headerShown: false }} />
      </Stack.Group>
      <Stack.Group screenOptions={{ presentation: "modal", headerShown: false }} options={{modalPresentationStyle: 'fullScreen'}}>
        <Stack.Screen name="Register" component={RegisterScreen} />
      </Stack.Group>
    </Stack.Navigator>
  )
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <MyStack />
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

This works perfectly fine, the modal shows. However, as you can see in this screenshot below, the modal is shown with modalPresentationStyle .automatic (in iOS). I want it to show as .fullScreen, so the hierarchy is not visible in the screen. Basically, I want the view to be shown from the safeArea/statusBar all the way down to the safeArea on the bottom.

[image: current modal presentation]

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The terminology in React Native isn't the same as terminology in native apps. If you want a full-screen screen, you probably don't want a modal. If you want a vertical animation, change the animation based on docs:

```js
screenOptions={{ cardStyleInterpolator: CardStyleInterpolators. forVerticalIOS, headerShown: false }}
```

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-navigator/#animation-related-options

There's also no `modalPresentationStyle: 'fullScreen'` in documentation and `Group` component doesn't take an `options` prop.

Comment: Dont't forget `import { CardStyleInterpolators } from '@react-navigation/stack';`

Answer (score 12):

[The accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69131377/3151675) states:

> If you want a full-screen screen, you probably don't want a modal.

That's not necessarily true. Use

```
screenOptions={{ presentation: 'transparentModal' }}
```

or

```
screenOptions={{ presentation: 'fullScreenModal' }}
```

for a full screen modal animation you can't dismiss on iOS.