# How to make a screen like this that you can close at the top on iOS

Tags: react-native, expo

in the picture below is a screen that is not full screen and you can close when you scroll the top to bottom. How is it done ?

[image]

Comment: Take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69130597/how-to-use-modalpresentationstyle-fullscreen-in-react-native-navigation.

Comment: use this library: react-native-raw-bottom-sheet

Answer (score 0):

If you are using React navigation v6, you can set the presentationType of the screen to modal.

```
const YourScreen = () => {
  return ()
};
```

```
<Navigator.Screen
   name="YourScreen" 
   component={YourScreen}
   options={{ presentation: 'modal' }}
 />
```